# cURL error (curl: (18) transfer closed with 349 bytes remaining to read)

Tags: curl, rpc

I'm not that familiar with cURL, so sending this request results in:

```
root@xyzxyz:~# curl --user 'username' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"helloWorld","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://192.168.56.1:8442
Enter host password for user 'username':
curl: (18) transfer closed with 349 bytes remaining to read
```

Password itself has been entered.
All related I fund was:

[not helpful, since this is for sure not a network problem (server is running on my local machine)](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1600)

Answer (score 0):

The pyBitmessage is a pure XML-RPC implementation and not a "JSON-RPC" like with Bitcoind. So the correct CURL syntax should be:

```
curl --user 'username' --data-binary '<methodCall><methodName>helloWorld</methodName><params><param><value><string>hello</string></value></param><param><value><string>World</string></value></param></params></methodCall>' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://192.168.56.1:8442
```